# laravel validation fails using the "numeric" rule, data is coming as number from form

Tags: php, laravel, validation, eloquent

I am using this kind of input form in my page:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="price" maxlength="4">
```

So as far as I know I can only input a number here and the form will accept a number and in theory send a numeric value to the controller.
However setting this validation rule:

```
$this->validate($request, [

    'price' => 'numeric|max:5'

]);
```

will make the controller not pass over this point, it doesn't even throw an error, the page gets reloaded and that's it.
I found out as I removed the 'numeric' from the rule and it all worked.
So what am I missing here? is the data passed from the form being passed as test instead?

Answer (score 2):

you are getting an redirect because the validation fails I assume you don't output anywhere he validation errors.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-size

when you use `numeric` with `max` you apply the following rule which uses `size`

> size:value
>
> The field under validation must have a size matching the given value.
>   For string data, value corresponds to the number of characters. For
>   numeric data, value corresponds to a given integer value. For an
>   array, size corresponds to the count of the array. For
>   files, size corresponds to the file size in kilobytes

which makes anything lower than 5 to be valid.

change the rule instead to

`numeric|min:1|max:99999`

or

`numeric|between:1,99999`

Also use something like [Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) in your development so you can get as much information from errors.

Comment: so how do you check that the number is no longer then five digits instead? like max 99999?

Comment: updated the answer with an example that you can work with